# WCF: Moving from development to production website

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I've got an ASP.NET website on my development server (test2.com) that contains two WCF services that are set up in their own IIS application in a subdirectory of that site (test2.com/services). Everything is working on this site as it should.  I'm now ready to move this website and the services to my production server (test.com and test.com/services), and I'm continually getting an HTTP 400 message no matter what I try.  I've updated the service references on the production website and renamed the appropriate references on the services to point to the production URL.  I've also made the appropriate updates in my client web.config file to the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IChatService" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOnlineUsersService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://test.com/services/ChatService.svc/services/chatservice.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IChatService"
    contract="Chat.IChatService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IChatService" />
  <endpoint address="http://test.com/services/OnlineUsersService.svc/services/onlineusersservice.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOnlineUsersService"
    contract="OnlineUsers.IOnlineUsersService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IOnlineUsersService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The appropriate web.config file on the service contains the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="ChatServiceLibrary.ChatService">
    <endpoint address="/services/chatservice.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ChatServiceLibrary.IChatService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="ChatServiceLibrary.OnlineUsersService">
    <endpoint address="/services/onlineusersservice.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ChatServiceLibrary.IOnlineUsersService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The web services themselves work fine if I call them from a web browser.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `http://test.com/services/onlineusersservice.svc`?  The relative address will be from the location of the .svc file, so your current config may actually be producing an address like `http://test.com/services/onlineusersservice.svc/services/onlineusesservice.svc`, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Tim: Just tried that.  I get the following back (partial): _The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. (then HTML)_  Basically, I get the HTML response back from the service, but the binding is looking for XML.